# In Prism, how can I allow modules to fill a control?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, modularity

I know I have to build a region adapter, but I don't have the slightest idea where to start. What I want is the ability to have modules populate a grid dynamically.

For example, think of it as little widgets populating a desktop space. If one is added, that one takes up the whole area, but as more are added, they are dispersed in a grid-like fashion.

I know you can create region adapters for controls, so would it be possible to build a region adapter for a listview or something of the sort to house these widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good resource that showed me what I needed to do - [MSDN Custom Region Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921129%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)